# Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS in android studio 2.2 stable release?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

**Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS. It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.**

I am not able to install app in my device but it gets install in the emulator without any error. Can anyone tell why this is happening and how to resolve this error so that i can install it in my device also

Comment: Please change your title to one *that summarizes the specific problem*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found out that there is some problem with android  instant run in studio 2.2.

The quick fix was that I disabled the instant run in android studio in Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run and it worked without an error.

Yes I was spliting the apk into "armeabi-v7a", "x86" and android studio was trying to install x86 into my device which was causing this problem.

Comment: Thank you for posting; this solution worked.  I also have split apks and ndk libs, and this error was driving me nuts after upgrading to studio 2.2 this morning.  I unchecked all four of the check boxes in the Instant Run settings, but you may be able to get away with unchecking fewer.

Comment: In my case unchecking first option did the job

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue. I haven't quite figured out what's causing it but it started when I chose to update Gradle to the latest release 2.2.0.

Couple of workarounds that I found:

- downgrade to previous release of Gradle. In my case going back to 2.1.3 fixed the problem
- if you have split APKs defined in your gradle file, remove 'x86' variant (I'm assuming that you're trying to install to ARM device). It seems that Android Studio tries to deploy the x86 version to the device.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215493#c32) was suggested another fix, just add `android.buildOnlyTargetAbi=true` in gradle.properties.